# Error when clicking on SharePoint Designer in SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server

When we click on SharePoint designer the error I get is:

> "This content cannot be displayed in a frame"  'To help protect the
>   security of information you enter into this website, the publisher of
>   this content does not allow it to be displayed in iframe'

[image]

Comment: Is there a question here? Can you outline what you're doing when this happens?

Comment: When I try to connect to sharepoint designer to edit sites ...I am getting this error

Comment: Is it opening a specific page? On launch of SPD? When does it happen and what have you previously customized?